# How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable in macOS

Tags: java, macos, vim, java-home

I am new to macOS. I know this question has been asked a lot before but all mentioned methods are not work for me.
I have tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gdpclEE-kA one also but it displayed an error like no such file or directory.(java version 16.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

(backticks) in .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

The default shell for macOS has changed to zsh so you would need to edit either `~/.zshrc`. So, you can do something like this:

```sh
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)' >> ~/.zshrc
```

This should work if you have jdk installed